# Why can't docker compose find uvicorn module

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I am new to docker and was trying to dockerize my fastapi application.
I built a Dockerfile shown below

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc
RUN apt-get -y install libnss3-tools
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -LJO https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/releases/download/v1.4.4/mkcert-v1.4.4-linux-amd64
RUN mv mkcert-v1.4.4-linux-amd64 mkcert
RUN chmod +x mkcert
RUN ./mkcert -install
RUN ./mkcert -cert-file cert.pem -key-file key.pem 0.0.0.0 localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3.8", "-m", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--ssl-keyfile=./key.pem",  "--ssl-certfile=./cert.pem"]
```

and ran the containers and they all worked. But when I try to combine the containers with docker compose its tells me can't find uvicorn module even when it's in the requirements.txt file .
Here is a snippet of my docker compose file containing the server service.

```
services:

  server:
    container_name: server
    image: python:3.8-slim-buster
    command: ["python3.8", "-m", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--ssl-keyfile=./key.pem",  "--ssl-certfile=./cert.pem"]
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /app
```

I have tried using changing the command part of the server service in docker compose to

```
command: bash "python3.8 -m uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --ssl-keyfile=./key.pem  --ssl-certfile=./cert.pem"
```

didn't work.
changed it to

```
command: sh -c "python3.8 -m uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --ssl-keyfile=./key.pem  --ssl-certfile=./cert.pem"
```

didn't work.

I removed the command totally it still didn't work, keeps showing

```
server | /usr/local/bin/python3.8: No module named uvicorn
server exited with code 1
```

Comment: Your `image` seems to reference the native python-slim-buster image, and not the one you've built: `image: python:3.8-slim-buster` - this should be a reference to _your already built container image_.

Comment: The image (python:3.8-slim-buster) you set for your service is not the one built from your docker file. Refer to the documentation on how to specify define the service to [use a built image from your dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/)

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks very much. It worked after using my custom built image.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule thanks chief it worked after doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you use in the docker compose is not the one previously built in the Dockerfile but a basic Python image.
You could build the image from your Dockerfile

```
docker build .  -t fastapi
```

then modify your `docker-compose.yml` file with something like this

```
services:
  api:
    image: fastapi
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

then run docker compose

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

Comment: It worked after doing this. Thanks very much